# How can I get a list of the top 100 most popular cities on Meetup?

Tags: meetup

[Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) has [a list of the top 10](http://www.meetup.com/find/) most popular cities. How can I see the top 100?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

Use their [api](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/#cities).  You'll need your api key

http://api.meetup.com/cities.xml/?key=API_KEY_HERE&order=members&page=100